# IntelliJ runs maven task and launches jar simultaneously?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have a run configuration set up to run a maven goal then launch a jar. IntelliJ seems to be running both at the same time. How can i configure it to run sequentially?

[image: My configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224676) in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 release. Update to [2019.3.1 or later version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).